# 18.04.1, no raid, no sound

Tags: 18.04, raid

I've just installed 18.04.1 in dual boot with Windows 10 on my (old but good) PC:

- Asus Maximus VI Gene
- Intel i7-4770
- 2x8GB DDR3 2400Mhz
- Gigabyte GTX770 4GB
- Samsung SSD 500GB 850 EVO
- 2x WD Black 2TB raid 0
- Sound Blaster Z
- Corsair Strafe RGB Cherry MX Silent
- Corsair Glaive RGB

After the installation I found:

- the mouse isn't detected at all (no issue with the keyboard). I had to use another mouse in order to use the system. I found this project: https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next and after installing `ckb` the mouse is now working and I can enjoy all the lighting effects and so on
- no sound at all. the sound card is "found": https://ibb.co/gTOH59 but I can get it to work. alsamixer shows this: https://ibb.co/cw2c59. the "default sound card" is "HDA NVidia". is this the problem? Have I to "force" the "HDA Creative" to be the default? how?
- I have a software (aka "fake raid") raid0 that Ubuntu didn't "found" during installation and now I don't know I to mount/use it.
  with `sudo fdisk -l` I get:

  ```
  Disk /dev/loop0: 86,9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


  Disk /dev/loop1: 140,9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


  Disk /dev/loop2: 2,3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


  Disk /dev/loop3: 14,5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


  Disk /dev/loop4: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


  Disk /dev/loop5: 34,7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


  Disk /dev/loop6: 3,7 MiB, 3887104 bytes, 7592 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


  Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: gpt
  Disk identifier: 57C2E2BD-DC31-11E7-9E0B-000F0031747B

  Dispositivo     Start      Fine   Settori   Size Tipo
  /dev/sda1        2048    923655    921608   450M Windows recovery environment
  /dev/sda2      923656   1128463    204808   100M EFI System
  /dev/sda3     1128464   1161239     32776    16M Microsoft reserved
  /dev/sda4     1161240 876780745 875619506 417,5G Microsoft basic data
  /dev/sda5   975745024 976771071   1026048   501M Windows recovery environment
  /dev/sda6   876781568 975744458  98962891  47,2G Linux filesystem

  Partition table entries are not in disk order.


  Disk /dev/sdb: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x00ee51dc

  Dispositivo Avvio Start       Fine    Settori Size Id Tipo
  /dev/sdb1             1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT


  Disk /dev/sdc: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  ```

and with "lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT" I get:

```
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE          TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   86,9M squashfs        loop /snap/core/4917
loop1  140,9M squashfs        loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop2    2,3M squashfs        loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop3   14,5M squashfs        loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop4     13M squashfs        loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop5   34,7M squashfs        loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop6    3,7M squashfs        loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop7  141,3M squashfs        loop /snap/skype/51
sda    465,8G                 disk 
├─sda1   450M ntfs            part 
├─sda2   100M vfat            part /boot/efi
├─sda3    16M                 part 
├─sda4 417,5G ntfs            part /media/dg74/WIN
├─sda5   501M ntfs            part 
└─sda6  47,2G ext4            part /
sdb      1,8T ddf_raid_member disk 
sdc      1,8T ddf_raid_member disk 
sr0     1024M                 rom
```

so, sdb and sdc are the two disk that are actually members of my RAID0.
How can I mount these disk/RAID0 **without** loosing any data?
thanks!

Comment: for the raid issue, I installed "dmraid" (sudo apt-get install dmraid) and rebooted.
now the raid is "seen" and I can access it (but in readonly).

still no luck for audio.

Comment: can I mark this question as "answered" or "closed" or whatever? I manage to fix all reported issue.